# Variance of Bernoulli random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, variance

> **Example 3.47** Let $0 \le p \le 1$. Recall that $X \sim \mathcal{Ber}(p)$ has probability mass function $\mathbb{P}[X=1] = p$ and $\mathbb{P}[X=0] = 1-p$ and the expectation $\mathbb{E}[X]=p$. Hence its variance is
>   $$
> \begin{split}
> \mathbb{Var} X
>  &= \mathbb{E}\left[(X-p)^2\right] \\
>  &= (1-p)^2 \mathbb{P}[X=1] + (0-p)^2\mathbb{P}[X=0] \\
>  &= (1-p)^2p + p^2(1-p) \\
>  &= p(1-p).
> \end{split}
> $$

I don’t understand the computation. It seems that we can just assume that we don’t need to expand the inner sum into $X^2-2Xp+p^2$. And $X$ is either one or zero. May we calculate the variance using the formula $E[X^2]-E[X]^2$ instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don’t understand the computation. It seems that we can just assume that we don’t need to expand the inner sum into $x^2-2xp+p^2$.

It's true that you don't *need* to expand that sum, although you certainly *could*. They're using the [Law of the Unconscious Statistician](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician): to find the expected value of a discrete random variable, you add up all its values weighted along with its probabilities of being those values. Here, the values of $(X - p)^2$ are $(1 - p)^2$ and $(0-p)^2$, because $X$ can be either $0$ or $1$.

It would have been fine to expand the inner term by FOILing, and you'd have arrived at the same result.

> And X is either one or zero. May we calculate the variance using the formula $E[x^2]-E[x]^2$ instead?

Yes.

Answer (score 2):

You can. Note that if $X \sim \mathcal{B}(p)$ then
$$
\begin{split}
\mathbb{E}[X]
 &= p\cdot 1 + (1-p) \cdot 0 = p\\
\mathbb{E}\left[X^2\right]
 &= p\cdot 1^2 + (1-p) \cdot 0^2 = p\\
\mathbb{Var} X
 &= \mathbb{E}[X^2] - \mathbb{E}[X]^2 = p-p^2 = p(1-p)
\end{split}
$$

What your text is using is the formula
$$
\mathbb{E}[f(X)] = f(1)\mathbb{P}[X=1] + f(0)\mathbb{P}[X=0] = pf(1) + (1-p)f(0)
$$
applied to $f(x) = (X-p)^2$, so $f(0) = p^2$ and $f(1) = (p-1)^2$, and the end result is
$$
\mathbb{E}[f(X)]
 = p\cdot (1-p)^2 + (1-p)\cdot p^2
 = p (p-1) [ (1-p) + p ]
 = p (p-1) \cdot 1
 = p(p-1),
$$
so the results are the same.